# Getting an image placed below a button

Tags: html, css

I have been working with several solutions on the web and have not found anything that works.

I am trying to do something that should be simple. I am trying to have an image of a "button" underneath an actual button.  When I do this, the image always overlaps the button itself.

HTML:

```
<div id="button">       <!-- Container for my image and button -->          
    <img src="C:\Users\Hansen\Desktop\Websigte\Images\buttonUnclicked.png"  />
    <input type="button" value="Roofing" onclick="createImageRoof();" style="position: absolute"/>  
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#button {
    height:30px;
    padding:3px;
    position:relative;

}

input[type=button] { 
font: 12px verdana,arial,sans-serif; 
width: 86px; 
float:left;
z-index:0;
}
```

Comment: a couple of <br/><br/> commands between your image and your input could move it where you want it

Comment: That stuck it too low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ruluw/1/edit)**

Use a background image for `#button` if you want

```
<div id="button">
  <input type="button" value="Roofing"/>    
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#button {
  width:90px;
  height:30px;
  padding:3px;
  position:relative;
  background: url(Images\buttonUnclicked.png);
}
#button > input { 
  position:absolute;
  left:5px;
  top:6px;
  width: 86px; 
}
```

Comment: Please note that the same answer was already answered by @EternalHour, mine is just a bit different in code, but the idea is there. (Noticed after posting my answer :| )

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using an actual image (which you won't be able to put behind anything), just make it a background image.

*CSS:*

```
#button {
    height:30px;
    padding:3px;
    position:relative;
    background: url('file:///C:/Users/Hansen/Desktop/Websigte/Images/buttonUnclicked.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

}

input[type=button] { 
font: 12px verdana,arial,sans-serif; 
width: 86px; 
float:left;
z-index:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you adjust the number for the left and the top in the CSS, you can move your picture around.  I called the picture #myImage in the HTML.  Hope that helps.

CSS

```
#myImage{
position:absolute;
left:10px;
top:50px;
}

#button {
    height:30px;
    padding:3px;
    position:relative;

}

input[type=button] { 
font: 12px verdana,arial,sans-serif; 
width: 86px; 
float:left;
z-index:0;
}
```

html

```
<div id="button">       <!-- Container for my image and button -->          
    <img id="myImage" src="C:\Users\Hansen\Desktop\Websigte\Images\buttonUnclicked.png"  />
    <input type="button" value="Roofing" onclick="createImageRoof();" style="position: absolute"/>  
</div>
```